# Not Worked md-form-field and getting errors

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When i am using `md-form-field` tag, i getting one error as describe bellow.

Error is:

```
ERROR Error: Found the synthetic property @transitionMessages. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
    at checkNoSyntheticProp (platform-browser.es5.js:2930)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setProperty
```

But i import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in `.module.ts` file but i getting error is describing bellow:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
    at new BrowserModule (platform-browser.es5.js:4161)
    at _createClass (core.es5.js:9528)
```

How to solve it?
My Material version is `@angular/material@2.0.0.beta.10` and `@angular/CDK@2.0.0.beta.10`.

**home.html file**

```
<md-form-field>
  <input type="text" mdInput >
</md-form-field>
```

**app.module.ts file**

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from './common/common.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './common/services/index.service';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './app.routing';
import {
   SessionModule
} from './session/session.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthService } from './common/services/authservice';
import { AuthGuard } from './common/services/auth-guard.service';
import { SourcesModule } from './sources/sources.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthLayoutComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutesModule,
    MaterialModule,
    SessionModule,
    SourcesModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Ayaz, you're exposing your secret API key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` to the `imports: []` section of your module. Make sure to install this package: `npm install --save @angular/animations`.

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

or

```
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

will provide the module you can import. Here's the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md).

Comment: Thankz Igor for Reply me.  Yes i install this package and my version is @angular/animations@4.0.0.

Comment: @ayazkodiya please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: when i import BrowserAnimationsModule or  NoopAnimationsModule then error occure as FruntEnd console as bellow:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
    at new BrowserModule (platform-browser.es5.js:4161)

Comment: @ayazkodiya could you update your question with the complete code of `AppModule`?

Comment: hi igor, i import BrowserAnimationsModule in home.module.ts then i added in app.module.ts and remove from home.module.ts then problem solved.
thnakz igor.